# ¿Se puede seguir buscando una imagen hasta que se encuentre en pantalla usando locateOnScreen de python?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo Python y he tratado de crear un Bot desde 0 para que realice un ciclo repetitivo de "X" acciones. Inicialmente, comencé usando coordenadas para interactuar con la pantalla, pero luego descubrí que sería más eficiente buscar imágenes. Sin embargo cuando realizo la búsqueda de una imagen en la pantalla, si la imagen no está disponible, el programa se salta esa acción y termina echando a perder todo el ciclo. Además en el caso de las pantallas de carga, el tiempo necesario puede variar.

Mi consulta es:
¿Hay otra función que repita "X" acción hasta obtener un resultado positivo?
Sé que esto se puede solucionar con un ciclo `while` y un buen uso de `time.sleep` o similar pero quiero reducir en lo posible (si incluso segundos) el tiempo que tarda un ciclo en terminar. Por lo tanto, quiero saber si es posible que la búsqueda de la imagen siga hasta que se encuentre.
Lo que llevo es algo así:

```
# Acá realizo la búsqueda de la primera imagen
object_6 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("IMG\IMAGEN1.PNG")

pyautogui.click(object_6)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(Cordenada2)
time.sleep(15)
### Como se puede apreciar uso el time.sleep para ajustar los tiempos
### pero si el tiempo de carga es mayor, él simplemente falla la búsqueda

### Acá busco el segundo objeto y si aun no ha cargado
### simplemente se salta el paso
object_7 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("IMG\IMAGEN2.PNG")
pyautogui.click(object_7)
time.sleep(4)
pyautogui.click(Cordenada2)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres usar `time.sleep`? ¿Por qué quieres esperar antes de volver a buscar la imagen?

Comment: La imagen es de un botón y este aparece después de "X" tiempo de carga, lo que trato es de eliminar por completo el uso de time.sleep con una linea de comportamiento como esta:  Busco Imagen hasta encontrarla>al encontrar imagen se da click en esta>se busca la siguiente imagen>se da click en esta, si la imagen no se encuentra en pantalla al momento de que el programa la busca simplemente no da click en esta eso es lo que trato de evitar con time.sleep pero es muy ineficiente

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué no hacer ese bucle tal y como lo describes, pero sin usar `time.sleep`?

Comment: Si no uso el time.sleep en el bucle el locateOnScreen deja de funcionar bien, no se por que pero deja de dar click y empieza a tratar de arrastrar el elemento, ademas de eso me preocupa sobrecargar los recursos del pc al hacer el spam con el ciclo while

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final solvente una manera para llegar a lo mas cercano a una respuesta y dejo la solución que encontré por si alguien cae en un error similar:
Básicamente No encontré forma funcional de evitar el uso de time.sleep en un ciclo funcional ya que la PC y el programa necesitan tiempo para reaccionar y proseguir con las acciones correctamente, de ahí el hecho que deje de dar clic y comience a arrastrar los objetos, la única forma de volver eficiente el uso del tiempo es con bucles, si estos no te llegan a funcionar solo debes ajustar el tiempo del time.sleep ya que probablemente es muy corto

while e <= Top_ciclo:
# acciona realizar

```
    # Primera accion
    while Bucle_1 == False:
            Bucle_1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Imagen.PNG")
            time.sleep(1)
    # Segunda accion
    while Bucle_2 == False:
            Bucle_2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("Imagen.PNG")
            time.sleep(1)
```